# How can I convert u8 mask to u32 mask with ARM NEON intrinsic?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, neon

There is a `uint8x8_t` mask, obtained from intrinsics like `vcgt_u8()`, with values like:

```
0, 0, 0, 0,255, 0, 255, 255
```

I would like to convert this mask to two `uint32x4_t` type masks. It seems `vmovl_u8()` and `vmovl_u16()` will still keep 255 instead of 65535 and 4294967295. How can I do this conversion?

Comment: So you want to widen with sign-extension instead of zero-extension?

Comment: @PeterCordes Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signed widen operation like `vmovl_s` will convert an all-ones pattern like 255 into 65535 and so on, so you need to `vreinterpret` your unsigned vector to signed, and back:

```
    uint8x8_t v = ...;
    int16x8_t i = vmovl_s8(vreinterpret_s8_u8(v));
    uint32x4_t low = vreinterpretq_u32_s32(vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(i)));
    uint32x4_t high = vreinterpretq_u32_s32(vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of `vmvnq_u32(vceqzq_u32(v))` calls and you've got it.